# bootstrap 4 carousel ignored, images stacked on top of eachother

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

I have looked at a lot of stack overflow posts on this topic and i didn't find any info on the behavior i'm seeing here.  My images are 300 x 300 and are appearing stacked on top of each other as if the carousel is not working at all.  There are obviously no sliders appearing either.  Here is my code :

```
<!-- Images -->
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" height="300px" width="300px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" height="300px" width="300px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/newyork.jpg" alt="New york" height="300px" width="300px">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Note that the rest of bootstrap is working beautifully.  Here are the imports i'm using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you are using is identical to [this w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) sample, which is for bootstrap 3!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think you need [this w3schools tutorial for bootstrap 4](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp).

Comment: That was it indeed!  Now i have another issue, my page looks exactly as i want but the sliding animation of the images is actually moving the component next to it during the sliding animation.  I assume this is not an issue on a full-width carousel but mine is just 300x300 pixels.  Is there a way to just see the main image part and not see the slided image next to it when the animation happens?

Comment: Hi Martin, this is a new question. I am not sure what is you code and what is the problem. I suggest asking a new question (ideally include the code snippet) so we could understand the problem quickly and help you out.

Comment: Trying to do that but apparently i can only post every 90 minutes :).  Will post a new question as soon as I'm able.

Comment: I found it.  I was not putting the carousel in its own column and the column next to it had just "col" as a class so it resized with whatever was happening next to it.  I changed the class to "col-9" and everything works now!  Thanks for your help!